# Inserting large text data in column defined as Text

Tags: c#, .net, sybase

I have a large string of over 35k characters that I want to save into a Sybase database column of type `Text`.

However I try to do it the string gets chopped.

I tried by just passing in the whole string to `System.Data.Odbc.ExecuteNonQuery()`.

And I also tried with:

```
OdbcParameter param = new OdbcParameter();
param.DbType = DbType.String; //Or DbType.AnsiString
param.Size = int.MaxValue;
param.Value = myBigString;
parameters.Add(param);
```

But no matter what I try the string of 39028 characters get chopped to 32,450.

Please note it's a third party database and so I cannot change the datatype of the Sybase column from Text.

Comment: Is there a limitation in the ODBC connection?  The `text` datatype shouldn't have a limit.

Comment: I am not a c# or .net developer but i would guess that your datatype in c# or .net maybe is truncating the data string or the ODBC connection can't handle it.